# Postfix error when sending emails - 554 5.7.1 - Relay access denied

Tags: email, ssl, postfix-mta

I have a new email server that uses Postfix (3.1.0) and Dovecot. I have managed to set up the TLS connection between the clients and the server, but I ran into a weird issue. Any time I try to send an email, I get this error: 554 5.7.1 - Relay access denied.
I googled this error and I found out that I need to set up `smtpd_relay_restrictions`, so I tried that. But nothing changed. Then I added `smtpd_sender_restrictions`, but again nothing changed.
I tried to send emails to different domains and using different networks on client device. Same error.

Here is my main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

myhostname = localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $myhostname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = class

mailbox_size_limit = 0
home_mailbox = Maildir/

virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000

recipient_delimiter = +

inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4

# TLS parameters
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.ro/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.ro/privkey.pem
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3

tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
tls_high_cipherlist = ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ADH-AES256-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ADH-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:NULL-SHA256
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noplaintext,noanonymous

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  permit_mynetworks
  reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, 
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unauth_destination
```

What could generate this error?

Comment: Can you include some log lines showing the 554 error.  They should be in /var/log/maillog.  This seems like an issue with auth since you do have permit_sasl_authenticated on relay and sender.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the Postfix settings:
To me it looks like your "mynetworks" setting:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

will only permit relay for clients on localhost via IPv4 / IPv6.

If the client was on the same LAN with a LAN IP of 192.168.0.100 I believe you would need to set as follows:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.100 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

If the client was on the internet with an IP of 9.9.9.9 I believe you would need to set as follows:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 9.9.9.9 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

Does that help?

As for dovecot there is a useful page on the wiki - If you haven't already, it is more secure to configure dovecot to require ssl/tls for auth login: 
https://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration